# OpenTK Integers Stop Changing Values after Window Open

Tags: window, opentk

I need to Have Integers that change in the Background while the GameWindow is Open in OpenTK i tested Some Things and It Totaly didn't work, after this code:

```
GameWindow polyWindow = new GameWindow(1024, 768);
polyWindow.Run(200);
```

the Folowwing Code:

```
if (Gamesets.Polygon.Playfield.timer == 2)
{
polyWindow.Close();
}
```

Does Not Execute, its Just a Basic Timer that Closes the Window after 2 
       Seconds, The Code for That is Here:

```
public static int timer;
public static int ms_timer;
public static void playfield()
    {

        while (true)
        {
            ms_timer = + ms_timer + 1;
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
            Console.WriteLine(timer + "S"+ms_timer + "MS");
            if (ms_timer == 100) { timer = timer + 1; ms_timer = 0; }
            if (timer == 10)
            {

            }
```

and it Does Not Work after the GameWindow is Shown

Answer (score 0):

Any code written after the GameWindow.Run() statement will not be executed until after the window has been closed. So the code checking if the time is equal to 2 will not run until polywindow.close() has already been executed or you manualy close the window.

Alternatively what you could do, is check the timer from within the Opentk window in the Update or Render methods and execute the Close() method there.

For example:

```
    protected override void OnUpdateFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnUpdateFrame(e);

        if (Gamesets.Polygon.Playfield.timer == 2)
        {
            Close();
        }
    }
```